# compress image (matrix) python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, compression

I want to compress a gray image whose dimension is 64x64 into 40x40 image

I tried scipy.fftpack.dct and scipy.fftpack.idct but the resulted image is not in high quality

Also tried numpy.savez_compressed the resulted image quality is very good but it has two disadvantage, One it save the compressed array in a file !!! I dont need it to save the compressed array in a file and the other disadvantage is that the compressed array dimension is arbitrary and not controlled

Does anyone know how to compress a gray image in a pre specified dimension- compressed array with high quality and without saving it in a file ?

Comment: FYI: I think most people would say you want to *resize* the image, not compress it.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the Python Imaging Library (PIL) . Documentation at http://www.effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm

Comment: The packages you used are fine however you need to use something in between. You need to use a low dimensional approximation with SVD.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153251/complex-vectors-and-shape-for-arrays It actually looks like this.